# ¿Como convertir las letras de un arreglo en mayúsculas excepto las 4 ultimas?

Tags: javascript, array, split

Buen día estoy aprendiendo JavaScript y estaba practicando con un pequeño ejercicio tengo un arreglo de tamaño 16, y quiero convertir las primeras 12 letras en mayúscula y las 4 restantes dejarlas en minúscula y finalmente mostrar el contenido del arreglo con las 12 letras mayúsculas y las 4 finales en minúscula pero estoy un poco atorado esto es lo que tengo de código al momento.

```
let texto = "abcdefghijklmnop"
texto.split("");

for (let i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
    texto[i].toUpperCase();
}
```

Espero me puedan orientar o brindar ideas que me puedan ayudar a resolver el código gracias.

Answer (score 2):

Se me ocurre que puedas emplear el metodo [`slice`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_slice_string.asp).

```js
let texto = "abcdefghijklmnop"

// El primer slice toma una porcion desde la posicion 0 a la posicion 12 (inclusivo)
// el segundo slice toma desde la posicion 12 en adelante

texto = texto.slice(0,12).toUpperCase() + texto.slice(12)
console.log(texto)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu solución mi intención era trabajar con un ciclo for pero de igual manera me enseñaste otra alternativa con la cual puedo dar solución a este problema.

Answer (score 2):

"Divide y conquista"

```
const texto = "abcdefghijklmnop"
// usamos un acumulador para no modificar el original
let accum = "";

for (let i = 0; i < texto.length; i++) {
    // convertir las primeras 12 letras en mayúscula 
    if(i < 12) accum += texto[i].toUpperCase();
    //  4 restantes dejarlas en minúscula
    else accum += texto[i];
}

console.log(accum)
```

Comment: Gracias por la solución me fue de gran ayuda, ya que mi objetivo era dar solución a este problema con un ciclo for

Answer (score 2):

Si quieres que los último 4 caracteres de tu cadena sean siempre minúsculas ya sea para cualquier longitud, podrías hacerlo de la siguiente forma:

```js
function mayusculas(texto) {
  let result = '';

  for (let i = 0; i < texto.length; i++) {
    if (i < texto.length - 4) {
      result += texto[i].toUpperCase();
    } else {
      result += texto[i];
    }
  }
  return result;
}
console.log(mayusculas('abcdefghijklmnop'));
console.log(mayusculas('abcdefghijklmnopqrstu'));
console.log(mayusculas('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'));
```

Comment: Es una solución bastante completa, esta solución lleva a un paso más allá la funcionalidad de lo que plantee en un principio gracias

Answer (score 1):

Pero con tu código casi lo logras, te faltó tener en cuenta que `split` retorna un `array` de letras (no modifica la variable actual). Por lo tanto tenias que asignarla.
Y también al final tenías que volver a convertir ese `array` en un `string`:

```js
let texto = "abcdefghijklmnop"
texto = texto.split("");

for (let i = 0; i <= 11; i++) {
    texto[i] = texto[i].toUpperCase();
}

console.log(texto.join(""))
```

Nota: Y faltó que fuera `i<=11` (te faltó el igual `=` porque eran 12 posiciones)

Comment: Muchas gracias, tu solución es bastante parecido a la solución que estaba tratando de dar en un principio, me quedo claro cuales fueron mi errores y las cosas que le faltaron a mi solución para que esta funcionará.